# Cron Job seemingly not registering arguments for PHP script, but the script is configured to except them

Tags: php, cron, argv

I'm scheduling dynamic cron jobs based on the contents of an Excel file with php, and passing those values to a script in `argv`.  My code is as follows:

```
$data = new SpreadSheet_Excel_Reader("sample-data.xls", false);

$surveyToken = "Token";
$email = rawurlencode($data->val(2, "B"));
$dateCompleted = rawurlencode($data->val(2, "C"));
$followUpOne = rawurlencode($data->val(2, "E"));
$followUpTwo = rawurlencode($data->val(2, "F"));
$programName = rawurlencode($data->val(2, "G"));
$subject = rawurlencode($data->val(2, "H"));
$firstName = rawurlencode($data->val(2, "I"));
$lastName = rawurlencode($data->val(2, "J"));
$learningGoal = rawurlencode($data->val(2, "K"));
$importanceScore = rawurlencode($data->val(2, "L"));
$confidenceScore = rawurlencode($data->val(2, "M"));
$strategies = rawurlencode($data->val(2, "N"));
$timeLine = rawurlencode($data->val(2, "O"));
$measures = rawurlencode($data->val(2, "P"));
$resources = rawurlencode($data->val(2, "Q"));

$output = shell_exec("crontab -l");
file_put_contents("crontab.txt", $output . "39 * * * * /usr/local/php53/bin/php mail.php $surveyToken $email $dateCompleted $followUpOne $followUpTwo $programName $subject $firstName $lastName $learningGoal $importanceScore $confidenceScore $strategies $timeLine $measures $resources" . PHP_EOL);
exec("crontab crontab.txt");
```

I'm using a raw URL decode in the mail.php script and sending that email by getting the variables from `argv`.

**I have tested this script by simply executing it on the command line with the outputted "url" and its arguments, not scheduling a cron job for it.**

When I execute it like that, it works fine.  When I run the code above, the cron job works well and the php file still emails me, but all the variables are empty from `argv`.

Comment: When you have run it, can you do a crontab -l or -e  (or view/edit crontab.txt) and check that there are not any special characters in your parameters - breaking the mail.php script?

Comment: Is the address for the email to you obtained from the $email parameter or built into your mail.php script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send arguments to the command line / `shell_exec`, you should not use `rawurlencode()` as it is not a url.

Instead, you should use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php); this escapes the variables correctly to be used in `shell_exec`.

Apart from that I would try to avoid dynamic scheduling like this; I would just run a cron-job every hour that reads the Excel file and includes the mail file. You could use a database of something similar if you want to generate a job queue.

Comment: But wouldn't my way be better because I wouldn't have to read over the file every day?

Comment: @Witch-King I don't think so as 1. you are adding cron-jobs and not removing them; that will lead to an uncontrollable number of jobs to run at the same time and 2. you might run into problems if the cron-job is set for a user that does not have the necessary permissions (the user running php, like the web-server).

Comment: @Witch-King By the way, what I would do (without seeing exactly what you are doing...), is add jobs to a database queue when your script runs and set a cron-job to run once an hour (or day, whatever...) to process the queue. That would be simple db-call to see if there are un-processed rows.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking if we did your way I could just scan the Excel file once a day...

Comment: The only thing is, would it be memory-intensive to read over the entire excel file every time? I don't really see any other way than using a database, but I need to use an excel file for this project anyways.

Comment: @Witch-King Even if it is once an hour that is still nothing for a web-server.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that does occur to me is that you should check that you have register_argc_argv set in your php.ini or using ini_set().

Comment: No, because it's just the cron job that is breaking the arguments.  The PHP script alone can accept them.